# How to bypass .NET Core 2.2 and 3.1 error handling and display standard IIS status code pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, error-handling

In Asp.NET Core 2.2 and 3.1 there is a method called Configure() in the Startup class where you declare what exception handling method you want to use. For example, if you want to send a custom response when an exception occurs, you can do the following:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor accessor, IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(delegate (IApplicationBuilder errorApp)
    {
        errorApp.Run(async delegate (HttpContext Context)
        {
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            Context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            await Context.Response.WriteAsync("An error occurred.");
        });
    });
    //var x = ((string)null).Length; <--if this is uncommented, the custom handler won't catch it
    //other configuration settings go here
}
```

Asp.Net Core will default to a standard developer exception page and show all the details of the exception if you don't define a custom handler.

My question is, how do I disable *both* the .Net Core developer exception page *and* the custom exception handler, and just have the errors bubble up to IIS so the old-fashioned error pages display?

The reason for wanting to do this is because custom handlers defined in the Configure() method only take effect after the Configure() method has completed. This means any exception that occurs in the Configure() method **(see the commented-out line in the example)** will send the user a full-blown developer error page, and there is (as far as I've researched) no way to disable this detailed developer page.

Obviously, I don't want these error details to appear on a production site. I figure disabling the Asp.NET Core error handling mechanism altogether will allow for 100% control of exceptions using the standard IIS error pages.

Comment: Comment the exceptionhandler mechanism you have and in the ConfigureServices don't use 
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't change any configuration and keep it as default, I assume you run .NET Core with IIS in in-process mode. You can try to `disableStartUpErrorPage` in [this guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1#start-up-error-page).

Remember, In-Process means your .NET Core process is running on the same process with IIS so whenever you got startup exception, it will be fallback into `Program.Main`, not in your `ExceptionHandler` delegate. That is the reason why user can see full stack trace.

Comment: I put disableStartUpErrorPage="true" on the <aspNetCore> element in web.config and it did the trick. it's properly showing IIS error pages now if an exception occurs in the Configure() method. thank you